Difference in Gauss-Newton method and Newton's method
TLDR: Is Newton's method only defined where m = n, and Gauss-Newton is simply an extension of it for overdetermined systems? Do they have any major difference?
I'm having some trouble understanding the difference between the two methods. I understand that Newton's method aims to find the $0$ of a function, and so if we want to minimize a function, we can also say that we want to find where it's gradient is $0$, wich is suitable for Newton's method, and so we use it on the function's gradient. Gauss-Newton method is usually used to solve nonlinear least squares problems, where we have a function $F(X) = (f_1(X), ..., f_m(X)), X\in {\rm I\!R}^n$, and the function we want to minimize is given by
$$L(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}f_i(X)^2$$
It's about here where I start to have some problems. Gauss-Newton method would minimize L given an initial solution $X^0$ with the iteration
$$X^{k+1} = X^{k} - (J^TJ)^{-1}J^TF(X^k)$$
where J is the jacobian matrix $\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}$ evaluated at $X^k$. It is true that $y = (J^TJ)^{-1}J^TF(X^k)$ is a solution to the linear system $Jy = F(X^k)$ if J is invertible. For now suppose that m = n, so J has a change of being invertible, and in this case, the Gauss-Newton iteration would be $X^{k+1} = X^k - J^{-1}F(X^k)$, but that is exactly the same as in Newton's method, for solving $F(X) = 0$. This makes sense, since if $F(X) = 0$, than $L = 0$, and as $L >= 0$, that is the solution to the minimization problem we had before. Now if m > n, than the linear system $Jy = F(X^k)$ is overdetermined, and it most likely does not have an exact solution. It's best approximation is given by $y = (J^TJ)^{-1}J^TF(X^k)$, wich as expected is what we use in the Gauss-Newton iteration. What I don't understand is: Is Newton's method only defined where m = n, and Gauss-Newton is simply an extension of it for overdetermined systems? For what it makes sense to me, the only thing that changed is the linear system we get in Newton's method, because now it is not solvable, and we need to approximate it with the least squares method, but the idea seems to still be the same. Is the only difference in both methods that in Gauss-Newton we can use an approximation to the linear system?
Oh btw, while I did use nonlinear least squares (an optimization problem) as an example, I'm not asking about Newton's method for optimization, but for solving the (in this case) overdetermined nonlinear system
I'm sorry if this is kinda of an silly question, but from the sources I looked at, I got the impression that both methods were not this much comparable, and I'm just wondering if I'm missing something.

The Gauss-Newton method is Newton's method applied to a nonlinear least squares minimization problem.  Gauss-Newton minimizes a function of the form
$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{m} f_{i}(x)^2$
by solving the nonlinear system of $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns,
$\nabla f(x)=0$.
It makes use of the special sum-of-squares structure of $f(x)$ in computing $\nabla f(x)$ and $\nabla^{2} f(x)$.

My interpretation is that Gauss-Newton tries to solve the nonlinear system where the i-th equation is $r_i = 0$, and of course it is overdetermined if we have more points than dimensions. In this case, $r_i = f_i(x)$, and $\nabla f(x)j = \sum{i=1}^{m}r_i \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial x_j}$, not simply $r_i$, isn't it? I don't really get when the gradient or even the laplacian appears. My question is more about is the Gauss-Newton in some sense the generalization that allows us to approximate overdetermined linear systems, but with nonlinear ones?
